# How to Hide Column Name in Sharepoint List Grouped View

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, I've created a grouped view from a list.

I want to list the value of the column that the list is categorised by but not the name of the column.

For example, the view is grouped by Category but I don't want the title 'Category:' to appear in front of every grouping as in:

Category: Asset Managment (2)

Category: Data Acquisition (5)

Category: General Admin (6)

I tried the following article, it hid the column name but not the colon. It also removed the ability to expand/collapse the items.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/how-to-hide-column-name-in-sharepoint-list-grouped-view/

```
<style> 
.ms-gb a:first-child{
display:block;
visibility:hidden;
} 
.ms-gb a:link > img {
display:inline;
visibility:visible;
position:relative;
top:13px;
right:5px;
} 
.ms-viewheadertr
{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

The end result should be column name and colon hidden. The ability to still collapse/expand items.

Comment: This won't work for SharePoint Online modern pages. The script editor web part has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

We can use jQuery to achieve it. Add the code into script editor web part in list view page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.ms-listviewtable td[class='ms-gb']").each(function() {
        elem = $(this)[0];
        var linkNode = elem.childNodes[0];
        linkNode.removeChild(linkNode.childNodes[1]);
        var textNode = elem.childNodes[1];
        textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.split(':')[1];
        linkNode.appendChild(textNode);
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]